# bootstrap form is not getting submitted

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and trying to submit form to PHP page. But `form` not getting submitted.

```html
<div class="container">   
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12">
      <ul class="timeline" data-offset-top="3">
        <li>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <form name="Wall_Post" id="Wall_Post" action="/update.php"  method="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="facebook-share-box">
              <div class="timeline-body">
                <div class="share-form">
                  <ul class="post-types">
                    <li class="post-type">
                      <a class="status" id="shareType" href="#"><i class="fa fa-file"></i> Status</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="post-type">
                      <a class="photos" id="shareType" href="#"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i> Photos</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="post-type">
                      <a class="videos" id="shareType" href="#"><i class="fa fa-film"></i> Video</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="post-type">
                      <a class="location" id="shareType" href="#"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Place</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <div class="share">
                    <div class="arrow"></div>
                    <div><textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="10" id="status_message" class="form-control message" style="height: 62px; overflow: hidden;" placeholder="What's on your mind ?"></textarea> </div>

                    <div class="image hide">
                      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image" id="image" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="video hide">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Youtube or Vimeo video URL" id ="videoUrl" name="videoUrl"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="place hide">
                      <input id="geocomplete" class="form-control" type="text" name="location" placeholder="Enter a location" />
                      <div class="map_canvas"></div>
                      <input type="hidden" name="lat" />
                      <input type="hidden" name="lng" />
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="shareType" class="shareType" value="status" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="timeline-footer clearfix">
                <div class="pull-right">
                  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post" id="btn-share" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>     
</div>
```

also I am using jquery `v1.11.1` in my website, same code is working fine in other page where jquery `v1.11.1` is not included. another thing i don't want to use ajax to submit form. is there any possibility ?

Comment: Any errors in the `console`? (Both of the pages) - My guess is that you have plugin that blocks the `submit`. When jQuery is not load, the plugin doesn't work.

Comment: after click on  button its not doing any action. no error no message

Comment: That's I understood but do you see any errors in the `console`? Do you know how to check this?

Comment: maybe is because you repeat the id "shareType" remember should be unique

Comment: bootstrap-modal.js:42 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'webkit' of undefined

Comment: so - nothing to do with this form code then..... you should change those duplicate id's though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is working just fine (altough there are some duplicate id's..). When I click the submit button the form submits to /update.php. So it must be javascript that is blocking the form to submit. Do you have any javascript files included? If yes, do they do something with submitting forms?

EDIT:
I found the problem after your comment with the javascript file: in your script.js you do a   `$("form").submit()` on line 12. At the end of this function, you do a `return false;`. This overwrites the submit process of each form. remove this `return false;` on line 47 and also the one at line 45 (or just remove the whole default part in your switch statement)!

Comment: yes you are correct same code is working fine in other page with out javasctip load. i dont know which javascript is stoping the form sumiting

Comment: thank you friend. you given me idea. none of the above is worked but i modified all js whichd is relate to form. now its working fine. conclusion is my JavaScript is stooping the form submitt

Answer (score 0):

One error is that you have multiple instances of identical id's ("shareType") - I don't know if that's causing the problem - but you should change these to be unique ID's for each link. An example of the replicated id is in the following:

```
<a class="status" id="shareType" href="#"><i class="fa fa-file"></i> Status</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you wrong to type `action="/update.php"` try change with `action="../update.php`

Comment: He said the submit button wasn't doing anything, so this is not the correct asnwer.

Answer (score 0):

As @Laurens says - you are doing a return false at the end of that function but also you are doing a switch statement based on the id of the form being submitted, with the default action being to return false in the case of the id not being one of the three stated. This means that this form (which is not one of the three listed) will trigger the default action and return false - therefore not submitting the form. You will need to add a switch case for this form like you have with the others